# Can you stop a view change happening in ionic when the $ionicView.beforeLeave event fires?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an ionic view with a form in it. When someone tries to leave the view (in my case by selecting a menu item) the `$ionicView.beforeLeave` event fires and I capture it in my controller. So far so good.

In the `$ionicView.beforeLeave` event handler I will check the data in the form and submit it to the server. If the data is not correct I want to tell the user and stop them leaving the form view so they have to correct the error.

I can't work out how to stop the change of view happening so the user stays on my form view.

Is there a way to do this? If so how?

Answer (score 1):

`$ionicView.beforeLeave` should be "cancellable" but it does not work.

You could do something like this, potentially:

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeLeave', function (event) {
 event.preventDefault();
});
```

but there's an issue [open](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/3791) which, apparently, hasn't been fixed yet.
The only option you have here is to cancel the event in the ui-ruote:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

});
```

Comment: Still, as of this writing, it appears that nightly build can do it but <=1.3.1 can't.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish it by adding this into your controller:

```
$scope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event){
  if($scope.shouldIStayOrShouldIGo=='stay') {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

**Example with confirm popup**

```
var go=false;
$scope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState){
  if(go===false) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $ionicPopup.confirm({
      title:'Are you sure you want to go?',
      cancelText:'No, stay',
      okText:'Yes, go'
    }).then(function(result) {
      if(result) {
        go=true;
        $state.go(toState);
      }
    });
  }
});
```